# What should I write/say on the "Do you have a job?" part in the immigration?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, philippines

I just graduated from college and going abroad as a tourist. One of the questions of immigration is if I have a job. Which is none because I just graduated and I'm having my vacation of life before getting a job. What should I write on that part on card? "Unemployed"?

Comment: The truth is usually a good option.  Imagine that you lie and are then asked for some evidence, how would that look?

Comment: @badjohn I think OP's question is more "how to phrase it" - should he put it as "Unemloyed" or other value, rather than "should he lie".

Comment: If the question is "Do you have a job?" the answer is "No." If the question is "What is your job?", then "unemployed" seems reasonable.

Comment: "Recent graduate" might also be fair, if you want to suggest that you're not intending to illegally remain in the country you're visiting and work there.

Comment: @Kuba I hope so but I thought that a reminder would not hurt.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to a landing card or, perhaps, a visa application, and it asks whether you have a job, the appropriate answer is no. Rather than putting 'unemployed' in that space, you might write, 'No, Gap Year.' Along with your age, it's commonly understood to be exactly as you are doing, having the time of your life travelling before spending the next 40 years 'Employed.'